# Mapdist: Error is.character(from)

Tags: r, google-maps

My dataset includes a column "pickup" corresponding to the starting coordinates and a "dropoff" for the ending coordinates, of a trip. Like:

```
pickup                 dropoff 
40.77419,-73.872608    40.78055,-73.955042
40.7737,-73.870721     40.757007,-73.971953
```

I want to calculate the shortest route suggested by Google Maps, and saved the calculations in a new column. This is what I'm doing:

```
 X$GoogleDist <- mapdist(from= list(X$pickup), 
    to = list(X$dropoff), 
    mode = "driving" ,
    output = "simple", messaging = FALSE, sensor = FALSE,
    language = "en-EN", override_limit = FALSE)
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
  Error: is.character(from) is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
library(ggmap)
X <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="pickup                 dropoff 
40.77419,-73.872608    40.78055,-73.955042
40.7737,-73.870721     40.757007,-73.971953")

X <- as.data.frame(lapply(X, function(x) sapply(as.character(x), function(y) URLencode(y, T) ) ), stringsAsFactors = F)
rownames(X) <- NULL

res <- mapdist(from= X$pickup, 
    to = X$dropoff, 
    mode = "driving" ,
    output = "simple", messaging = FALSE, sensor = FALSE,
    language = "en-EN", override_limit = FALSE)
cbind(X, res)
#                  pickup                dropoff                  from                     to     m     km    miles seconds minutes     hours
# 1 40.77419%2C-73.872608  40.78055%2C-73.955042 40.77419%2C-73.872608  40.78055%2C-73.955042 12805 12.805 7.957027    1212   20.20 0.3366667
# 2  40.7737%2C-73.870721 40.757007%2C-73.971953  40.7737%2C-73.870721 40.757007%2C-73.971953 14038 14.038 8.723213    1437   23.95 0.3991667
```

Your columns are probably of type `factor` (check with `str(X)`). `mapdist` needs `character` vectors (check `?mapdist`). So you have to convert the columns using `as.character` beforehand. Also, when using geo coordinates, I think you got to URL encode them. I.e. the comma `,` becomes `%2C`. Otherwise it didn`t work for me...

Comment: I am running the same code you wrote but I keep getting:   

   -   matching was not perfect, returning what was found.
      Error in `*tmp*`[[c(1, 1)]] : no such index at level 1   -

Thanks!

Comment: When running the example code above, or when running with your real data? If the latter one, could you provide it? (e.g. add `dput(mydata)` to your post or upload it to e.g. dropbox.

Comment: when running the example above.

Comment: Never mind, I believe I could have exceeded the query limit. Thanks a lot!.